# storage of multidimensional arrays fortran 90

Tags: fortran, nested-loops, fortran90

I have

```
module mymod
contains
  subroutine mysub(matrix_dum, i_size, j_size)
    integer :: i, j, i_size, j_size
    real(8), dimension(:,:) matrix_dum
    do j=1, j_size
      do i = 1, i_size
        matrix_dum(i,j) = 11.d0*matrix_dum(i,j)
      end do
    end do
  end subroutine mysub
end module mymod 

program main
  use mymod
  implicit none
  real(8), dimension(:,:,:), pointer :: matrix 
  integer :: i, num_matrices, i_size, j_size
  num_matrices = 11
  i_size = 5000
  j_size = 6000
  !only one of them are uncommented in actual practice
  !I have two choices this choice takes a very very long time
  allocate(matrix(num_matrices,i_size,j_size))
  matrix = 11.d0
  do i = 1, num_matrices
    call mysub(matrix(i,:,:),i_size,j_size)
  end do

  !this one does the same job instantly
  allocate(matrix(i_size,j_size,num_matrices))
  matrix = 11.d0
  do i = 1, num_matrices
    call mysub(matrix(:,:,i),i_size,j_size)
  end do
  deallocate(matrix)
end program main`
```

Why does the second work as I expected but the first does not. I know it must be the way Fortran stores multidimensional arrays in a single line with memory locations one after the other. But I am not sure about my syntax. Am I correctly passing the addresses of the matrices? or am I telling it to copy the entire matrix instead of giving it the address. How do you pass the pointer to a section of a multidimensional array? what is going on here?

Answer (score 3):

Typically Fortran processors store arrays in the array element order defined by the language - such that the left most subscript varies fastest as you move from element to element.

So all the elements of matrix(:,:,1) will be contiguous - located next to each other.

The elements of matrix(1,:,:) will not be contiguous if SIZE(matrix,1) /= 1.

Operations on arrays that are not in array element order or that are not contiguous are often slower (e.g. they may be less cache friendly or may, in some cases, require the construction of intermediate temporary arrays).